# Why doesn't my variable render in my view after populating it in my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What am I doing wrong? `angular.min.js` is in the folder `js`. I am using the book from O'Reilly. There is an example like this. But on my PC it doesn't work.

```js
//controller.js

function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
        <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: try define an angular module first, tons of good examples/tutorials online

Comment: What's the error in the `console` ?

Comment: when i define a module it work, but i was want understand how he will work like this

Comment: It will never work like this without declaring the module @ricardopatrickmarinhodesou Also it looks like you have a very old book on angularJS, you don't declare `controllers` with global `function ExampleController () {}` anymore!

Comment: More than likely it's just an abbreviated example, not meant to be run verbatim.

Comment: If you need to understand AngularJS flow , i recommend you [this course] (https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) which is free. Will guide you on the basics and make you do some coding too

Comment: well may before work? i are in first example of book in first pages yet no come learning about modules because this i was want udnerstand why no working :), may the book is old?

Comment: @twodave that's a pretty silly statement ... in older angular versions that allow global functions as controllers it would work just fine

Comment: Maybe it was just an uninformed statement, though if you had called me silly personally I'd have to agree :)

Comment: ok...  caling you out on that!  :)

Comment: ok ty all is answered my doubt :)

Comment: Remain calm.  The example as posted will work fine in Angular 1.2.  Angular 1.3 removed the capability of using stand alone functions as controllers.  I would suggest using a newer book that specifically targets 1.3 or later.

Comment: try naming the app in `ng-app`

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you are referring to old book. Please update your controller as below

   //controller.js 
   `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);` 
   `app.controller('HelloController', function($scope) {`
           `$scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };`
    `});`

and in HTML
`ng-app="myApp"`

Please try and let us know whether it is working or not